# Одно событие onClick для нескольких кнопок

Tags: android

Использую `Android Studio`.
Например, есть три кнопки и один метод `onClick`.

```
rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
tvHello = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.label_hello_kitty);

public void buttonRed_Click(View v){
        tvHello.setText(R.string.res_btn_Red);
        rl.setBackgroundResource(R.color.res_col_red);}
```

Как внутри `buttonRed_Click` узнать по какой кнопке щёлкнули?

Answer (score 8):

```
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId()) 
        {
            case R.id.first_button:
                break;
            case R.id.second_button:
                break;          
        } 
     }
```

Comment: А если в case нужно впихнуть 2 строки, нужно ли использовать {} или нет? Те примеры и описания, которые я нашёл в тырнете глагольствуют только про одну строку в case.


Вот пример:

switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonRed: {tvHello.setText(R.string.res_btn_Red);
                rl.setBackgroundResource(R.color.res_col_red);};
            break;
.....
.....
.....
}

Comment: нет, можно писать сколько угодно, но если вас  смущает, то можете завернуть все в операторные скобки или вынести в отдельный метод, главное про break не забывать, иначе все перейдет к следующему case

Answer (score 6):

Ответ уже дан, но думаю стоит разъяснить для будующих пользователей.

Любой виджет(контрол) в Android унаследован от базового класса [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). В свою очередь каждому `View` можно поставить в соответсвтвие некоторый идентификатор (далее `ID`).

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/my_button"
....
/>
```

`ID` обычно назначаются в xml и используются для нахождения контрола в текущем дереве всех View.

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Детектирование нажатия(`click`) на любой `View` (не обязательно `Button`) происходит по средством реализации интерфейса [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html). Это можно сделать двумя способами: имплеменировав этот интерфейс `Activity` либо создать инстанс анонимного класса (`new View.OnClickListener()`). Но главное что надо сделать - это в обязательном порядке переопределить метод `OnClick()` интерфейса `View.OnClickListener`. Да, и не забыть, что надо назначить необходимому контрлу его слушателя (`view.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)`). В добавок один слушатель можно назначить для любого количества контролов.

Как различать по какому `View` было совершено нажатие? Достаточтно только посмотреть на сигнатуру метода `onClick` интерфейса `View.OnClickListener`:

```
public abstract void onClick (View v){}
```

Внутри этого метода разработчики позволяют нам использовать ссылку на `View`, по которому было совершено нажатие (в данном случае это `View v`). Осталось просто отличать различные view по их индивидуальному признаку. Тут нам на помощь приходит идентификатор `ID`. Метод [view.getId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()) возвращает нам значении идентификатора коткретного контрола. Осталось только сопоставить его.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.my_button1:
                    //выполняем необходимое действие
                    break; // вызывается для выхода из блока switch (при вызове дальнейший код не исполняется)
                case R.id.my_button2:
                    //выполняем необходимое действие
                    break;
                case R.id.my_button3:
                     //выполняем необходимое действие
                    break;
                case R.id.my_button4:
                    //выполняем необходимое действие
                    break;
            }
        }
```

ps. Стоит обратить внимание, что для системы ID является значением типа int.

pps. Есть еще 1 способ детектирования нажатия, посредством прямого вызова метода:

```
        <Button
        android:onClick="method"
        ...
        />
```

В этом случае просто вызывается указаный метод. Более подробно про этот вариант почитать тут

Comment: Спасибо, познавательно.

Answer (score 3):

по `View v`, который Вам параметром передается. Это и есть ссылка на кнопку.

Comment: я догадывался, но не мог понять, почему именно View

Comment: Потому, что View это базовый класс. Этот трюк позволяет прицепить один обработчик и для кнопок, и для других элементов, которые могут обработать клик. В противном случае пришлось бы для каждого типа сочинять свои обработчики. А если ещё свой собственный класс создать, тогда совсем плохо будет.

Answer (score 3):

```
v.getId()
```

думаю дальше уже понятно

Answer (score 0):

Используйте **android-annotation**, избавит вас от написания рутинных строк кода, что плодотворно скажется на производительности))

вот [пример](http://androidannotations.org/) в котором, в том числе, на две вьюхи вешается один обработчик.

Comment: вот только для новичков я бы крайне не рекомендовал такое. Провоцирует глобальное непонимание базовых принципов, в будущем приводит к трудновылавливаемым багам (если не постигнуть базовые принципы). А о увеличении бинарника я просто молчу.

Comment: @KoVadim, действительно лучше о увеличении бинарника просто молчать, потому что это __миф))__
если человеку нужны базовые принципы то вот в помощь https://code.google.com/p/iosched/ . здесь ищут быстрый и четкий ответ на конкретную задачу. я без преувеличения считаю что научившись подключать аннотации и мало-мальски использовать их человек в жизни не вернется к стандартным способам разработки под андроид.
что косается скрытых багов - скажу только одно - в проаннотированом коде в 200 строк легче найти баг чем в коде без аннотаций на 600 строк.
использовать или нет это дело каждого __лично))